# How to use PHP-YAML's custom tag callbacks?

Tags: php, yaml

According to the [official documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.yaml-parse.php), there is a way to provide callbacks for custom YAML tags:

```
mixed yaml_parse ( string $input [, int $pos = 0 [, int &$ndocs [, array $callbacks ]]] )
```

> *callbacks*
>   Content handlers for YAML nodes. Associative array of YAML tag => callback mappings.

However, there seems to be no other documentation on the subject, even in the extension source!

I created this script as a test:

```
<?php

$yaml =<<<YAML
---
prop: !custom val
YAML;

print_r(yaml_parse($yaml,0,$n,array(
  YAML_STR_TAG => function () {
    echo "YAML_STR_TAG\n";
    $args = func_get_args();
    print_r($args);
    return 'x';
  },
  '!custom' => function () {
    echo "!custom\n";
    $args = func_get_args();
    print_r($args);
    return 'y';
  }
)));
```

And I got this output:

```
$ php yaml.php
YAML_STR_TAG
Array
(
    [0] => prop
    [1] => tag:yaml.org,2002:str
    [2] => 1
)
!custom
Array
(
    [0] => val
    [1] => !custom
    [2] => 1
)
Array
(
    [x] => y
)
```

From that I can tell several things:

- The key used in the callback lookup is either one of PHP-YAML's [predefined constants](http://us.php.net/manual/en/yaml.constants.php) or the custom tag used in the YAML source, including the exclamation point
- Each key **and** value in a map gets "tagged" and passed to the matching callback, probably because according to the YAML spec the key can be any valid type as well.
- Three arguments are passed to the callback: the "subject" of the tag, the tag itself, and some number, probably corresponding to a `YAML_*_SCALAR_STYLE` constant.
- The return value of callbacks replaces the tagged data structure

Can anyone confirm the expected behavior of this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much research and testing, I have found some answers.

As found in the extension's [unit tests](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/yaml/trunk/tests/yaml_parse_008.phpt?view=markup), each callback takes three arguments:

- *mixed* `$data` - The tagged data, already parsed
- *string* `$tag` - The tag name, expanded according to the [offical YAML tag specs](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id896044):

  - `!custom` expands to `!custom` if no tag prefix is defined
  - `!custom` expands to `prefixcustom`, where `prefix` is defined by the document meta-data `%TAG ! prefix`. Note there is *not* a leading exclamation mark
  - `!!preset` expands to the parser-defined internal type. See the [`YAML_*_TAG`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/yaml.constants.php) constants
  - `!<verbatim-tag> expands to` verbatim-tag`. Note there is *not* a leading exclamation mark.
- *integer* `$style` - The scalar style used. See the [`YAML_*_SCALAR_STYLE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/yaml.constants.php) constants

The callback should return a mixed value for the parser to emit.